# Private files and Nginx configuration

Tags: 7

How to configure Drupal 7 to have private files folder. And also this configuration is secure within Nginx config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set up a private files folder, navigate to: *Administration » Configuration » Media » File system*.  Create a path from the *Unix* root for the "Private file system path" (e.g. `/var/files`) outside of the Drupal root.

Make sure that this folder is readable and writable by the web server user.

By having this folder *outside* of the Drupal root, it is secure.  It cannot be compromised through the web server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So can I use "/var/files" for the creation in Private file system path or there's a certain or exact config? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, the gist of the answer is that you can use `/var/files` (or any *other* path that is outside of the Drupal root) as the private file system path.  There is no exact config , the path `/var/files` is just the one I happen to use myself.